# JPA - Redirect one entity Update/Delete statements to a mirror table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am working with Java EE 7 on a Wildfly server. I have a strange scenario, where the client has two tables - "employees" and "employees_modified". The second table has the exactly same structure as the first one and servers as a modification storage. So if an employee changes his name from "john" to "john-1", we will write to employees_modified

```
insert into employees_modified(first_name) values("john")
```

Please note that the other fields in the table "employees_modified" are empty.

The question is: is there a way to somehow map the two tables and overwrite the values from employees by those in employees_modified where they are present.

I looked at @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) and @AttributeOverrides but those solutions don't seem to fit to my scenario.

Comment: I would suggest a trigger on MySQL table

Comment: It seems cascading provides you requirements.

Comment: I think StanisIavL's suggestion is probably the best course of action.

Comment: Does the first table remains immutable and all changes are propagated to the modified table?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comments. The problem is that I have limmited access to the database and cannot change its structure, so I need to find a way to map this in JPA.
@VladMihalcea yes the first table is immutable and modifications are stored only in the second one

Comment: You might take a look at [Hibernate interceptor](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html). Nice thing about it is that in `onFlushDirty()`, which is called when entity is updated, is that you get `currentState` and `previousState` for each field so you can easily extract only changed values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at [hibernate envers](http://envers.jboss.org/), it solves your problem simply. Attach envers to your project. Place the first table under audit with annotation @Audited and @AuditTable(value = "employees_modified"). But as pointed by @Predrag Maric it is important to leave other fields of the second table empty, you can use @PostPersist (or listener in pure hibernate) method in entity. In this method you can describe additional logic employees_modified entity creation and persisting.

Comment: Envers would populate all the fields in audit table, not just the modified one.

Comment: @sashok_bg is it important for you?

Comment: @AlexanderFedyukov at this point - yes. I think however that ENVERS is the bes solution in my case, since the whole idea was to create auditing and revisions for the "emplyee" table, but was just done really poorly. I will start working on envers solution and see how it fits. Thank you all !

Answer (score 1):

You can use [@SQLUpdate](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLUpdate.html) and [@SQLDelete](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLDelete.html) to customize the CRUD statements to be [redirected to a different table](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Hibernate_Annotations_Reference_Guide/entity-hibspec-customsql.html):

```
@Entity
@SQLUpdate( sql="UPDATE employees_modified SET name = ? WHERE id = ?") 
@SQLDelete( sql="DELETE FROM employees_modified WHERE id = ?")
public class Employees {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This annotations overrides default behavior of current entity persisting. How its solves the problem?

Comment: According to the OP comment: "yes the first table is immutable and modifications are stored only in the second one". So, the Employees table remains immutable, no rows can be updated deleted, and all changes are redirected to the other table. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

If it's only for auditing, I agree with the answers before me (triggers, events etc).

If you actually want to access that "employees_modified" table (e.g. run complex Hibernate queries) than you can use a second persistent unit. The following post: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/237078 seems to indicate that's a recommendation from hibernate. Obviously the 2nd unit will need xml configuration rather than annotation - at least it can't rely on the same @Table annotation.

BTW there's also some documentation about a @SecondaryTable annotation, but it's my understanding that it doesn't match your case (because your business probably needs to treat those tables differently - sometimes you want to view just the history, sometimes just the live data)/